# Get the total amount of messages published on a vhost in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to get the total amount of messages published to a vhost in RabbitMQ (during the last minute or something like that)? I have checked the [RabbitMQ Management HTTP Stats documentation](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/31c1d2668d39/priv/www/doc/stats.html) but it seems to work only for a specific object, such as queues/exchanges/channels.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.6.10 I can see that `http://localhost:15672/api/vhosts` and `http://localhost:15672/api/vhosts/${vhost}` (e.g. `%2F` for `/`) do have:

```
message_stats: {
    publish: 632,
    publish_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    confirm: 0,
    confirm_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    return_unroutable: 0,
    return_unroutable_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    get: 0,
    get_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    get_no_ack: 0,
    get_no_ack_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    deliver: 998,
    deliver_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    deliver_no_ack: 20,
    deliver_no_ack_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    redeliver: 522,
    redeliver_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    ack: 466,
    ack_details: {
        rate: 0
    },
    deliver_get: 1018,
    deliver_get_details: {
        rate: 0
    }
}
```